# Flutter Filter Chips in wrap has odd spacing on web

Tags: flutter

I have used the Flutter wrap widget with filter chips and it looks great on Android and iOS but it seems to break on Flutter Web. Is this a bug in flutter web or somethign with my code?

**Flutter Android/iOS**

[image]

**Flutter Web**

[image]

Looks like flutter web ignores spacing of the wrap.

**Code**

```
Wrap(
                    spacing: 10,
                    children: listOfPackTags.map(
                      (category) {
                        return FilterChip(
                          selected: selectedTags.contains(category),
                          onSelected: (bool selected) {
                            if (selected) {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedTags.add(category);
                              });
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedTags.remove(category);
                              });
                            }
                          },
                          label: Text(category),
                          showCheckmark: false,
                          selectedColor: const Color(0xFF93C3B9),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`MaterialTapTargetSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialTapTargetSize.html). The default value is `MaterialTapTargetSize.padded` on mobile platforms and  `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` on others.

You could configure it in the `ThemeData` or per `Widget`.

```dart
ThemeData(
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
),

FilterChip(
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
  ...
),
```